# how to enable OpenEJB log

Tags: java, logging, openejb

I am using Eclipse to create (Session Bean + MDB), deployed in OpenEJB. It works. Now how can I output the log debug info to console ? I need to add a log4j.properties in the project or to change the OpenEJB server properties ?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176924/how-to-configure-openejb-logging/4280414#4280414

Answer (score 0):

You need to add log4j.properties to your classpath and add the following configuration to log the OPENEJB debug to the console.

```
log4j.category.OpenEJB                 = warn
log4j.category.OpenEJB.server          = info
log4j.category.OpenEJB.startup         = info
log4j.category.OpenEJB.startup.service = warn
log4j.category.OpenEJB.startup.config  = info
log4j.category.OpenEJB.hsql            = info
log4j.category.CORBA-Adapter           = info
log4j.category.Transaction             = warn
log4j.category.org.apache.activemq     = error
log4j.category.org.apache.geronimo     = error
log4j.category.openjpa                 = error
```

You can modify the logging by changing the Log Levels.